# Java creating a JSON object results in a status 404

Tags: java, json, tomcat9

I am creating a JSON warning using:

```
String warningString = "{\"empty\":\"No YM specific lines\"}";
json = new Gson().toJson(warningString);
json = json.replaceAll("^['\"]*", "").replaceAll("['\"]*$", "").replace("\\", "");
```

While this works I though there would be a better way to do this and found:

```
import com.google.gwt.thirdparty.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
try {
    obj.put("empty", "No YM specific lines");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, this results in a status 404 when I test. I have checked the logs and can not find any errors. I am using Apache Tomcat/9.0.46.

Changed to:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

String json = null;
if (ymSpecificLineDetail == null) {
    //Gracefully return a warning message
        
    json = new JSONObject().put("empty", "No YM specific lines").toString();    
} else {
    json = new Gson().toJson(ymSpecificLineDetail);
}
    
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your imports to:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Comment: Try json-20210307.jar.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question with the new code added. Now I get an error on the line response.getWriter().write(json); "Change type of 'json' to 'int' with "write" underlined. I checked the json and it is generated correctly as {"empty":"No YM specific lines"}

Comment: Found the answer. I should have String json = new JSONObject().put("empty", "No YM specific lines").toString();